# jQuery get .html of DOM and use switch/case to dynamically update DOM

Tags: php, jquery

```
var WinBack = $('div.jWinBackFrom').html();

switch(WinBack) {
    case '1': //If database returns 1 : set Verizon FiOS logo
    $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/assets/images/verizon-fios-logo.jpg" />');
    break;
    case '2': //If database returns 2 : set DirecTV logo
    $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/directv-logo.jpg" />');
    break;
    case '3': //If database returns 3 : set DISH Network logo
    $('div.jWinBackFrom').prepend('<img id="WinBackLogo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/dish-network-logo.jpg" />');
    break;
}
```

Ok so the database returns 1,2,or3. I need the jQuery to determine which is returned so I am checking the DIV to see what it's contents are. Then I want an image to display based on what is the contents which is why I am using a switch case.

```
<div class="jWinBackFrom"><?php echo $optimum['cWinBackFrom'][$i]; ?></div>
```

I have a table which returns multiple rows of data, each needs to be dynamically updated by jQuery.

so row 1 may be cWinBackFrom = 1 (which would load the FiOS logo) and subseqent rows may be cWinBackFrom = 2 (which would load the DirecTV logo) and so forth.

1. PROBLEM 1: image is not displaying. console says access is
   forbidden. autoload -> helper -> url is active.
2. PROBLEM 2: all images are showing fios which is not correct. because
   the second row is 2, which should load the direcTV image.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The idea behind switch case is that you just have to say the switch part once.

Comment: Yes that is the idea isn't it. Now help me solve my problems please! :) thank you

Comment: Problem 2: `$('div.jWinBackFrom')` matches multiple elements. `html()` will return the content of the first matched element, but `.prepend()` will affect *all* matched elements. Wrap your code in `$('div.jWinBackFrom').each(...)` .